# WPF - View getting minimized during navigation

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, mvvm

I have a WPF application which behaves weird when another application is also opened. 'Another' application is developed using Panther. WPF apps behaves correctly with all other apps in the machine.

While both the applications opened, and when we click next on the WPF app, the app getting minimized even though its active as per windows active event.

WPF application is built using galasoft and follows slightly different approach in navigation compared to the pattern available when we search.

We initiate the Page from app.xaml.cs and based on the click, we invoke currentPage.Hide() and nextPage.Show() methods. All the navigations are written within App.xaml.cs file. Through a delegate the button click will be passed to app.xaml.cs file and the pages are switched.

Did anyone else face similar kind of issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I managed find an answer/work around to this issue.

In the existing design, the sequence of actions were Hide() the current view and Show() the next view.

Now, we modified the sequence to perform Show() the next screen first and then hide() the current screen. This way, the window was kept active and was visible to the user.